# Converting string date to datetime

Tags: python

I'm trying to clean some list data by extracting date.

I have my list data with the code below :

```
for i in item_list[1::2]:
    print(i)
```

Sample of the data :

```
Before Audio Described PerformancesNext Performance: Friday  22 June 2018  6.30 PM
Tickets from £20.00Next Performance: Sunday  27 May 2018  10.00 AM
Tickets from £9.50Next Performance: Tuesday  29 May 2018  7.30 PM
Tickets from £5.00Next Performance: Thursday  31 May 2018  4.00 PM
```

I need to extract the date/time info a datetime type.

I've tried with

```
for i in periods[1::2]:
    print(i[i.find(':')+2:])
```

This gives me :

```
Friday  22 June 2018  6.30 PM
Sunday  27 May 2018  10.00 AM
Tuesday  29 May 2018  7.30 PM
Thursday  31 May 2018  4.00 PM
```

I've then applied :

```
for i in periods[1::2]:
    datetime.strptime(i[i.find(':')+2:],'%A  %d %b %Y  %I.%M %p')
```

This works so far but bugs out with the error on one of the dates:

```
'Sunday  14 October 2018  2.30 PM' does not match format '%A  %d %b %Y  %I.%M %p'
```

Any ideas why this string isn't being converted?

Comment: I think the `%b` in your code should actually be `%B` since your month names are not abbr but full.

Comment: That did the trick.  Add as answer